# How to get RewriteRule to redirect both existing and non-existing pages?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Goal:** Send all requests, regardless whether the directory/file exists or not, to `http://example.com/index.php`

**What I have tried:**

```
Rewrite Engine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php [L]
```

It redirects URL's of non-existing directories/files fine, but when I access an existing subdirectory and file `http://example.com/test/test.php` it only gives me the contents of the `test.php` page instead of the main `index.php` page.

If I understand correctly, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` tell it to perform the `RewriteRule` if those criterias are met, which makes sense why it only redirects on non-existing directories and files.  But I've tried removing those `RewriteCond`'s, and all it does is put my site into a redirect loop.

I've also tried doing

```
Rewrite Engine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php [L]
```

But then it doesn't redirect at all.

What do I have to put to accomplish this?

Comment: Well that your last try is nonsense, should be pretty obvious – that something is _not_ an existing file/directory, _and_ at the same time _is_ an existing file/directory is a bit unlikely, hm? // And what you need to do, is add an exemption that does not rewrite the request if it is for the `index.php` file already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example would only redirect things that does not exist to your `index.php` as the conditions you have there:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Basically means if file or directory does not exist, do this.

Your second example is even worst as it tries to see if a file, directory exist and does not exist which makes no sense.

---

To redirect anything existent or not to a main handler in this case `index.php` all you need is the below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The condition makes sure you're not redirecting it to yourself to prevent a loop. If you're running HTTPD version 2.4 and above you can simple use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ index.php [END]
```

The flag `[END]` takes care of not executing any further redirects.

Comment: My second example wasn't that thought out.  But your first suggestion worked, and looking at it makes me feel kind of foolish now.  I don't know why I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: glad it worked out for you and you understood what you were doing wrong ;)